# CardBackgroundColor remains Grey when I want to set a custom color, whereas default colors works fine

Tags: android, kotlin, colors, card

CardBackgroundColor remains Grey when I want to set a custom color, whereas default colors works fine.

For instance, Card.setCardBackgroundColor(R.color."customcolor") don't set the custom color. The color is grey, whereas Card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED) works fine.

I have tried:

- To take color without alpha
- to set to 0dp elevation
- Card.setCardBackgroundColor(color."customcolor")

No results.

**EDIT :**

Card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF")) works. But I have to hardcode the color. Any idea on a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyy,

You have to get the color from the resources like this

```
Card.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.'your color'));
```

Edit

As you are getting a context from your adapter, so

```
Card.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.'your color'));
```

That works perfectly!!

Comment: Thx for your reply. but in my PC, getResources() is not recognized. getResources() is highlighted in red...I have to add something to my config files ?

Comment: If you are using it in fragment, then getActivity() or context.'Card.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.'your color'));

Comment: I use it in a adapter. I don't understand your comment. You have put the same expression than above.

Comment: Great ! It works. :) Many thanks. 

I see getcolor is deprecated. Is it a problem ? Can I leave like that ?

Comment: Its fine, old thing always works,  And tick it up

Answer (score 0):

Card.setCardBackgroundColor method take color as parameter instead of colour resource Id, so it is failing while you supplied the id.

So right way for using the color resource is like below.

```
 Card.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color));
```

Comment: ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color) is a Int. ParseColor wants a String. it doesn't work.